# Django cannot use pk on upload_to in an object yet saved

Tags: django, django-uploads

I have built a wizard in my project. 
In the first step I create an object "Building" and save it in the db. 
In the second step I let the user upload an image of the building saved in the first step.

The image is in the Building's model.

When I try to customize the saving path of the image, I found out that "instance.pk" is None.

The same thing happen if I try to access every attribute of the Model that should be in "instance". The only attributes that I can access are those I manually set in the View (ex. nome, descrizione, ...)

I don't undersant why is happening this. Could somebody explain it to me?

Part of the Model:

```
 class Building(models.Model):
    utente = models.ForeignKey(User);
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    descrizione = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    link = models.URLField(blank=True)
    foto = ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True)
    ...
```

Content_file_name:

```
 def content_file_name(instance, filename):         
    estensione = '.jpg'       
    posizione_punto = filename.rfind('.')        
    if posizione_punto > 0:
            estensione = filename[posizione_punto:]
    return '/'.join(['buildings', str(instance.pk), 'vetrina'+estensione])
```

Part of the View (2nd wizard step):

```
 # I load the building from the db
 building = get_object_or_404(Building, pk=b_id)

 if request.method == 'POST':

       form = StepOneForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            building.data_update = datetime.datetime.now()
            building.nome = data.nome
            building.descrizione = data.descrizione
            building.link = data.link
            building.foto = data.foto

            building.save()

            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you've defined your `foto` field as `foto = ImageField()` it should probably be  `foto = models.ImageField()`

Secondly, when you initiate your form you're not including the `instance` argument (have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)). It should be something like -

```
form = StepOneForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=building)
```

That's how django knows to add the html form data to an existing instance. If you declare your form like this -

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class BuildingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Building
```

Then when you do `data = form.save(commit=False)` your `data` variable is actually an instance of `Building`. And if you've already said that the form relates to a specific instance (eg the `building` you declare at the beginning of your view), then `data` will be that specific instance of `Building`.

This means that you can change your view code to -

```
def your_view(request):
    building = get_object_or_404(Building, pk=b_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BuildingForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=building)
           if form.is_valid():
               building = form.save(commit=False)
               building.save()
    else: #...
```

Have a look at the [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/) and [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) Docs.

Comment: For the 1. point, I'm using sorl.thumbnail, see here the [docs](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#model-examples)
For the 2., I don't get how it's related with my problem: I'm coping the data from the form to the "building" object...

Comment: OK, now I get it...
Thank you for the help!